# Jquery how to set active link css color

Tags: jquery, css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f9FDs/

How can i get the link color to change to the active link (last clicked) color specified in CSS?

```
// Active Menu Link
jQuery("#navbar-main li a").live('click', function () {
    jQuery("#navbar-main li a").removeClass("selected");
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `.live()` method is deprecated and removed from new jQuery versions. use `.on()` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a deprecated method which doesn't exist in the version of jQuery that you posted in the fiddle.

Switch from `live()` to `on()`

http://jsfiddle.net/f9FDs/4/

Please note that if you're using `live()` for dynamically generated elements, the `on()` eqvivalent takes 3 arguments to make use of event delegation:

```
jQuery("#navbar-main").on('click', 'li a', function () {
```

Comment: First one to get there, all be it by 30 sec :)

Answer (score 6):

"live" is deprecated. Use "on" instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9FDs/3/

```
jQuery("#navbar-main li a").on('click', function () {
    jQuery("#navbar-main li a").removeClass("selected");
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 but to be more optimal : `jQuery(".selected").removeClass("selected");`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon If you want better performance, consider `$('#navbar-main').find('.selected').removeClass("selected");`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - That would be more optimal, unless the "selected" class is used elsewhere.